# How do I download gridded sst data?

Tags: heatmap

I've recently been introduced to `R` and trying the `heatwaveR` package. I get an error when loading `erddap` data ... Here's the code I have used so far:

```
library(rerddap)
library(ncdf4)
info(datasetid = "ncdc_oisst_v2_avhrr_by_time_zlev_lat_lon", url = "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/erddap/")
```

And I get the following error:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(x$url$url, handle = x$url$handle) : 
>     schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308) - The token supplied to the function is invalid

Would like some help in this. I'm new to this website too so I apologize if the above question is not as per standards (codes to be typed in a grey box, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone directed this post to my attention from the heatwaveR issues page on GitHub. Here is the answer I provided for them:

I do not manage the rerddap package so can't say exactly why it may be giving you this error. But I can say that I have noticed lately that the OISST data are often not available on the ERDDAP server in question. I (attempt to) download fresh data every day and am often denied with an error similar to the one you posted. It's gotten to the point where I had to insert some logic gates into my download script so it tells me that the data aren't currently being hosted before it tries to download them. I should also point out that one may download the "final" data from this server, which have roughly a two week delay from present day, as well as the "preliminary (prelim)" data, which are near-real-time but haven't gone through all of the QC steps yet. These two products are accounted for in the following code:

```
# First download the list of data products on the server
server_data <- rerddap::ed_datasets(which = "griddap", "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/erddap/")$Dataset.ID

# Check if the "final" data are currently hosted
if(!"ncdc_oisst_v2_avhrr_by_time_zlev_lat_lon" %in% server_data)
  stop("Final data are not currently up on the ERDDAP server")

# Check if the "prelim" data are currently hosted
if(!"ncdc_oisst_v2_avhrr_prelim_by_time_zlev_lat_lon" %in% server_data)
  stop("Prelim data are not currently up on the ERDDAP server")
```

If the data are available I then check the times/dates available with these two lines:

```
# Download final OISST meta-data
final_info <- rerddap::info(datasetid = "ncdc_oisst_v2_avhrr_by_time_zlev_lat_lon", url = "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/erddap/")

# Download prelim OISST meta-data
prelim_info <- rerddap::info(datasetid = "ncdc_oisst_v2_avhrr_prelim_by_time_zlev_lat_lon", url = "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/erddap/")
```

I ran this now and it looks like the data are currently available. Is your error from today, or from a day or two ago? The availability seems to cycle over the week but I haven't quite made sense of any pattern yet. It is also important to note that about a day before the data go dark they are filled with all sorts of massive errors. So I've also had to add error trapping into my code that stops the data aggregation process once it detects temperatures in excess of some massive number. In this case it is something like1^90, but the number isn't consistent meaning it is not a missing value placeholder.

To manually see for yourself if the data are being hosted you can go to this link and scroll to the bottom:
https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/index.html

All the best,
-Robert